# Why isn't my simple unmatched query not working?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

```
SELECT [Denial Query].BlPerFct_RcvGrpBlPerId, ATBDetailDaily.ClaimNo, 
ATBDetailDaily.EncRpt_EncStsMne, ATBDetailDaily.Payer, 
ATBDetailDaily.PayerHealthPlan, ATBDetailDaily.EncStpDate, 
ATBDetailDaily.BlPerFct_TotBalAmt
FROM ATBDetailDaily 
LEFT JOIN [Denial Query] ON 
ATBDetailDaily.[BlPerFct_RcvGrpBlPerId] = [Denial Query].[BlPerFct_RcvGrpBlPerId]
WHERE ((([Denial Query].BlPerFct_RcvGrpBlPerId)="IsNull") 
AND ((ATBDetailDaily.Payer)<>"Guar - Pers"));
```

I’m trying to get the BlPerFct_RcvGrpBlPerId rows that are in the ATBDetailDaily, that are not in the Denial Query.... I'm just trying to extract all rows out of the ATBDetailDaily that are not captured in the Denial Query using a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause should read:

`WHERE [Denial Query].BlPerFct_RcvGrpBlPerId Is Null`

Currently you're asking it to match the literal string `"IsNull"`, but what you need to do is check if is exists at all, which is what the `Is Null` comparison does.

Comment: Thanks for your response, even after making the change to "Is Null" it doesn't pull any rows... I tried IsNull to see if it would at least show something....

Comment: You should change the SELECT clause as well, so that `ATBDetailDaily.[BlPerFct_RcvGrpBlPerId]` is selected rather than `[Denial Query].BlPerFct_RcvGrpBlPerId `, since the `[Denial Query]` version will always be empty.